# Actionscript 3 - Setting color of variables in a string

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm pretty new to Flash and I'm struggling with defining the text-color of a variable within a compound String. Here's what I have so far:

```
// VARIABLES FROM HTML

var var1:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters.var_1;
var var2:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters.var_2;
var var3:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters.var_3;
var var4:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters.var_4;

var var5:Object = "HEADLINE NEWS: ";
var5.color = "#a92400";

// COMPOUND STRING

var var6:String = var5 + " " + var1 + " " + var2 + " lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.";
```

Any ideas? I've tried a bunch of things so far but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do here. Do you want to set color to a TextField?

Comment: No, I just want to change the color of the text variable "var5" (HEADLINE NEWS) within the compound string. The compound string is part of a marquee scroller in flash which pulls in various variable to make a whole sentence. I just want to style that specific text

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you're trying to do is set color to text, but you want to do it by using objects. This is possible, but that is what the [TextField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html) is created for, as the above comment suggests, along with the [TextFormat](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextFormat.html) object.

So  normally you would do something like this:

```
private var tf:TextField = new TextField();
private var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();

private function setFontBoldAndColor():void{
tf.text = "Lorem ipsum";
format.font = "Arial";
format.color = 0xFF0000;  //red
format.bold = true;

tf.setTextFormat(format);
}
```

You could, if you want, pass an object as follows (assuming you created an object called lbl and used dot notation, e.g. lbl.color = 0xFF0000):

```
    private function setLabel(lbl:Object):void {

        format.font = "Arial";
        format.color = lbl.color;
        format.bold = true;
        format.size = lbl.size;

        _label = new TextField();
        _label.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
                    //a few other TextFormat properties if you want....
        _label.background = false;
        _label.border = false;
        _label.selectable = false;
        _label.alpha = lbl.alpha;
        _label.text = lbl.someText;
        _label.setTextFormat(format);
        addChild(_label);
```

All you need to do is to make sure that the objects you're creating have properties which correspond to those of the TextFormat object.

Comment: I suggest setting property `_label.htmlText`, which supports partially colored strings: `_label.htmlText = "<FONT COLOR=\"#FF0000\">Lorem ipsum</FONT> dolor sit amet."`